# Secant method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have perfomed the Secant method in MATLAB as follows:

```
%Implementation of the secant method.

function c = secant2(x0, x1,eps)

format long e

fx0 = f(x0);                   
fx1 = f(x1);                   
if abs(fx1) < abs(fx0),         %c is the current best approx to a root.
  c = x1;  fc = fx1;
else
  c = x0;  fc = fx0;
end;
fprintf('initial guesses: x0=%d, x1=%d, fx0=%d, fx1=%d\n',x0,x1,fx0,fx1)
if abs(fc) <= eps             % check to see if initial guess satisfies
  return;                       % convergence criterion.                      
end;



while abs(fc) > eps,
  fpc = (fx1-fx0)/(x1-x0);      % this is the secant approx to f'.

  if fpc==0,               %% if fprime is 0, abort.
    error('fprime is 0')   %% the error function prints message and exits
  end;

  x0 = x1;  fx0 = fx1;             %% save previous iterate
  x1 = x1 - fx1/fpc;               %% secant step
  fx1 = f(x1);
  if abs(fx1) < abs(fx0),          %% store best approx to root in c.
    c = x1;  fc = fx1;
  else
    c = x0;  fc = fx0;
  end;
  fprintf('   x0=%d, x1=%d, fx0=%d, fx1=%d\n',x0,x1,fx0,fx1)
end;

function fx = f(x)
    fx = x-tan(x);
    return;
```

The thing is that this is supposed no to converge but it gives

```
 secant2(1,2,10^-6)
initial guesses: x0=1, x1=2, fx0=-5.574077e-01, fx1=4.185040e+00
   x0=2, x1=1.117536e+00, fx0=4.185040e+00, fx1=-9.355037e-01
   x0=1.117536e+00, x1=1.278759e+00, fx0=-9.355037e-01, fx1=-2.047554e+00
   x0=1.278759e+00, x1=9.819084e-01, fx0=-2.047554e+00, fx1=-5.152181e-01
   x0=9.819084e-01, x1=8.820982e-01, fx0=-5.152181e-01, fx1=-3.327476e-01
   x0=8.820982e-01, x1=7.000875e-01, fx0=-3.327476e-01, fx1=-1.423505e-01
   x0=7.000875e-01, x1=5.640071e-01, fx0=-1.423505e-01, fx1=-6.853868e-02
   x0=5.640071e-01, x1=4.376483e-01, fx0=-6.853868e-02, fx1=-3.026248e-02
   x0=4.376483e-01, x1=3.377447e-01, fx0=-3.026248e-02, fx1=-1.345669e-02
   x0=3.377447e-01, x1=2.577501e-01, fx0=-1.345669e-02, fx1=-5.863760e-03
   x0=2.577501e-01, x1=1.959730e-01, fx0=-5.863760e-03, fx1=-2.547959e-03
   x0=1.959730e-01, x1=1.485017e-01, fx0=-2.547959e-03, fx1=-1.101340e-03
   x0=1.485017e-01, x1=1.123608e-01, fx0=-1.101340e-03, fx1=-4.752504e-04
   x0=1.123608e-01, x1=8.492712e-02, fx0=-4.752504e-04, fx1=-2.047731e-04
   x0=8.492712e-02, x1=6.415760e-02, fx0=-2.047731e-04, fx1=-8.817364e-05
   x0=6.415760e-02, x1=4.845148e-02, fx0=-8.817364e-05, fx1=-3.794967e-05
   x0=4.845148e-02, x1=3.658380e-02, fx0=-3.794967e-05, fx1=-1.632969e-05
   x0=3.658380e-02, x1=2.762008e-02, fx0=-1.632969e-05, fx1=-7.025644e-06
   x0=2.762008e-02, x1=2.085142e-02, fx0=-7.025644e-06, fx1=-3.022464e-06
   x0=2.085142e-02, x1=1.574097e-02, fx0=-3.022464e-06, fx1=-1.300219e-06
   x0=1.574097e-02, x1=1.188281e-02, fx0=-1.300219e-06, fx1=-5.593207e-07

ans =

     1.188281151181448e-02
```

So what did I do wrong? (I have seen on http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-tan%28x%29&lk=4&num=1 that the roots are not in the interval `[1,2]`.)

Comment: I don't understand.  What exactly is your problem statement?  Do you have an issue of your secant method converging or not converging? Also, what is the function you are trying to find the root of?  It is not given in your current problem statement.  BTW, in hindsight, your secant method code looks like it's correct.  Did you try this with another function with a well defined root?   Try something like `x^2 - 4`, where there are two roots at `x = 2` and `x = -2`.... and see what happens.

Comment: Well the problem is that my method is converging when is not suppose to do it :) and my question is what I have wrong Thnks :)

Comment: Then what can be done?

Comment: What can be done is that you actually read the book where you copy all this code from and stop asking lots of questions where we have to decipher some code which you did not even write.

Comment: Excuse me but I didn't get this from a book, but I have a lot of doubts because I am knew in this but my question is serious. And please be less rude with your comments, not everyone has the same level here, and that doesn't mean that we are not serious, with respect everyone helps in a better way to each other, that is the main goal of this site .

Comment: You got it from a website: https://www.math.washington.edu/~greenbau/Math_464/secant.m .  Though not specifically required, it is customary to attribute where you got the source code from... especially since anything you post here is part of the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License (CC-BY-SA 3.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Basically, it allows people to use material here freely so long as SO is referenced.  Using code that doesn't allow this behaviour is contrary to this license. This code does not guarantee this behaviour... keep that in mind.

Comment: And this allows to people to be rude and disrespectful?, Well I didn't knew the above information and may be I had a mistake, and I apologize of that, but I think anyone has the right to tell somebody that rude things and well may be I should stop practicing and reading about this until I am someone that knows everything and can ask questions of the level is require in this site.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the behaviour of anyone.  I was just commenting on the fact that you're using code and placing it on this website that you may not have permission to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is starting to look whole lot like homework...

There is nothing wrong with your algorithm. The secant method is not a bracketed method, meaning that it is not going to remain between the initial points you specify. The point you report, which is approximately zero, is a valid root for your equation `x-tan(x)=0`.

I strongly suggest you google "convergence criteria for root finding" to learn more. In this case, if you set a bound on your relative error in `x` you will find that it cannot be satisfied. I also recommend you read the Wikipedia page on root finding (here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) in depth to gain a better understanding of the subject.

There are also plenty of books that discuss this subject in detail. One of the most accessible and cheap ones is "Scientific Computing: An Introductory Survey" by Heath

Comment: Right, to clarify, this is not homework, it is practice, and thanks for saying that this code is right :), And well the thing is that I am only concentrating in the interval [1,2].